# How to interate based on words in text? (Shell Scripting)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a file currently in the form

```
location1 attr attr  ... attr
location2 attr attr  ... attr
...
locationn attr atrr  ... attr
```

What I want to do is go through each line, grab the location (first field) then iterate through the attributes. So far I know how to grab the first field, but not iterate through the attributes. There are also a different number of attributes for each line.

```
TEMP_LIST=$DIR/temp.list

while read LINE
do
        x=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo $x
done<$TEMP_LIST
```

Can someone tell me how to iterate through the attributes?
I want to get the effect like

```
while read LINE
do
    location=`echo $LINES |awk '{print $1}'`
    for attribute in attributes
        do something involving the $location for the line and each individual $attribute
done<$TEMP_LIST
```

I am currently working in ksh shell, but any other unix shell is fine, I will find out how to translate. I am really grateful if someone could help as it would save me alot of time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to DreadPirateShawn's solution, but a bit simpler:

```
while read -r location all_attrs; do
    read -ra attrs <<< "$all_attrs"

    for attr in "${attrs[@]}"; do
        : # do something with $location and $attr
    done
done < inputfile
```

The second `read` line makes use of bash's herestring feature.

Comment: If we assume that none of the attributes contain whitespace, can be even simpler: `while read -r location attributes; do for attr in $attributes; do stuff; done; done < filename`

Answer (score 0):

This might work in other shells too, but here's an approach that works in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMP_LIST=temp.list

while read LINE
do

    # Split line into array using space as delimiter.
    IFS=' ' read -a array <<< $LINE

    # Use first element of array as location.
    location=${array[0]}
    echo "First param: $location"

    # Remove first element from array.
    unset array[0]

    # Loop through remaining array elements.
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "   Value: $i"
    done

done < $TEMP_LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using awk in your posted code, why not learn how to use awk, as it is designed for this sort of problem.

```
while read LINE
do
    location=`echo $LINES |awk '{print $1}'`
    for attribute in attributes
        do something involving the $location for the line and each individual $attribute
done<$TEMP_LIST
```

is written in awk as

```
#!/bin/bash
tempList="MyTempList.txt"

awk '{  # implied while loop for input records by default
    location=$1
    print "location=" location    # location as a "header"
    for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {
        printf("attr%d=%s\t", i, $i) # print each attr with its number
   }
   printf("\n")     # add new-line char to end of each line of attributes
}' ${tempList}
```

If you want to save your output, use `awk '{.....}' ${tempList}> ${tempList}.new`

Awk has numerous vars that it sets as it reads your files. `NF` mean NumberOfFields for the current line. So the for loop, starts at field 2, and prints all remaining fields on that line in the format provided (change to suit your needs). The `i<=NF` drives the ability to print all elems on a line.
Sometimes you'll want the 3rd to last elem on line, so you can perform math on the value stored in NF, like `thirdFromLast=$(NF-3)`. For all variables that are numbers, you can "dereference" it as a value, and ask awk to print the value stored of the $N(th) field. i.e. try

```
print "thirdFromLast="(NF-3)
print "thirdFromLast="$(NF-3)
```

... to see the difference that the `$` makes on a variable that holds a number.

(For large amounts of data, 1 awk process will be considerably more efficient that using subprocesses to gather parts of files.)

Also work your way through this tutorial [grymoire's awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

IHTH